Solve $x^{\frac{5}{6}}+x^{\frac{2}{3}}=2x^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Solve $x^{\frac{5}{6}}+x^{\frac{2}{3}}=2x^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$x^{\frac{5}{6}}+x^{\frac{2}{3}}-2x^{\frac{1}{2}}=0$
$x^{\frac{1}{2}}(x^{\frac{1}{3}}+x^{\frac{1}{6}}-2)=0$
Let $w=x^{\frac{1}{6}}$
$\Rightarrow w^3(w^2+w-2)=0$
$w^3(w+2)(w-1)=0$
Therefore:
$w^3=0 \Rightarrow x^{\frac{1}{2}}=0 \Rightarrow x=0$
$w=-2 \Rightarrow x^{\frac{1}{6}}=-2 \Rightarrow x=(-2)^6=64$
$w=1 \Rightarrow x^{\frac{1}{6}}=1 \Rightarrow x=1$
$x=0,1$ works in the original expression. $x=64$ does not.
Question:
I did not square the original expression, nor is there a denominator where the variable $x$ can't be $0$. So why then does it produce a solution $x=64$ that doesn't work?

Ahhh, but you did! Raising $w$ to the $6$th power (or any even power) loses sign information: $x = w^6 = (w^3)^2$. Notice that $w = +2$, which doesn't solve the polynomial equation in $w$, also produces the same value $x = 64$, which doesn't solve the equation in $x$.

Remember to do sanity checks when doing your proofs. $x^\frac{1}{6} = -2$ should trigger an alert. $x^\frac{1}{6}$ is defined as the positive sixth root of $x$.

This has something to do with the reason we always restrict the base to be positive when dealing with expressions like $x^{1/6}$ (where the denominator of the exponent is an even intger).
Note:  $w=x^{1/6} \geq 0 \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow x^{1/6}=-2.$

As mentioned before, you have raised. In this way, you have to take care. All raising operations must be done in complex domain if exponents are fractions. Furthermore, when you believe you have found the solution, probably some of them will not satisfy the original equation because they do not belong to the first Riemann sheet. They will obey the original equation but not in the first sheet. What does it mean?
In a computer, if you do $(-1)^{1/2}$ it will return only $i$ but it has the other solution.
In any case, you can take some a function I've been working on to solve. See it here
$$x^{1/3} + x^{1/6} = 2$$
$$x^{1/6} (1 + x^{1/6}) = 2$$
$$x^{1/6} e_1(x^{1/6}) = 2$$
$$\implies x^{1/6}=W_1(2) = \{1; -2 \}$$
substituting at first equation
$$\implies x^{1/3}=2-W_1(2) = \{1; 4 \}$$
clearly, the first solution is $x=1$ but $x=64$ also satisfies but not in the first Riemann sheet.
